# Why, Fatal error: Class 'PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase' not found in ...?

Tags: php, fatal-error, classnotfoundexception

Why I'm getting this PHP error?

```
Fatal error: Class 'PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase' not found in ...
```

Comment: You are not providing any information at all.

Comment: Run your tests via the phpunit command-line. It loads up the necessary classes.

Comment: You can also use the answer from the following answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42811164/class-phpunit-framework-testcase-not-found/42828632#42828632 to keep your code compatible with PHPUnit 6 as well as earlier versions.

Answer (score 74, accepted):

The [PHPUnit documentation](http://www.phpunit.de/manual/current/en/writing-tests-for-phpunit.html) <s>says</s> used to say to include/require PHPUnit/Framework.php, as follows:

```
require_once ('PHPUnit/Framework/TestCase.php');
```

**UPDATE**

As of PHPUnit 3.5,  there is a built-in autoloader class that will handle this for you:

```
require_once 'PHPUnit/Autoload.php';
```

Thanks to Phoenix for pointing this out!

Comment: PHPUnit 3.5 comes with its own autoloader that might help keep things simple:  `require_once 'PHPUnit/Autoload.php'`

Comment: +1 Phoenix, I also recommend reading up on autoloading in PHP it can be fairly useful to write one's own autoloader script.

Comment: I concur that require_once('PHPUnit/Autoload.php') is the best practice.

Comment: I don't have both `PHPUnit/Autoload.php` and `PHPUnit/Framework/TestCase.php`, my folder is kind of like `PHPUnit/Framework/MockObject`

Comment: Looks like the documentation has changed since I posted this answer. Sorry I can't really offer more insight, I haven't recently used PHPUnit - I just Googled the answer for this one ;)

Comment: From where it will load the PHPUnit/Autoload.php and PHPUnit/Framework/TestCase.php as my folder only contains GShoppingContent.php as I want to use google base to upload items automatically

Comment: and now I have 
`PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required 'PHPUnit/Autoload.php'`

Comment: see @shadi's answer for PHP 6+ http://stackoverflow.com/a/42561590/2883328

Answer (score 283):

For those arriving here after updating phpunit to **version 6 or greater** released on 2017-02-03 (e.g. with composer), you may be getting this error because phpunit code is now namespaced (check <strike>[changelog](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/blob/master/ChangeLog-6.0.md#changed-1)</strike> [changelog](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/blob/9d0c024d2099531442d862b66b0ad7cf35ed8e78/ChangeLog-6.0.md) ).

You will need to refactor things like `\PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase` to `\PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase`

Update 2023-03-30: updated changelog link based on comment

Comment: Thanks, I had this problem due to Travis CI using the most recent PHPUnit version on their PHP 7 builds. My fix was to manually download an old phar and use that instead.

Comment: https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/wiki/Release-Announcement-for-PHPUnit-6.0.0
it's on the top of the release notes, yet I missed it

Comment: Thank ye kindly, good sir. I am indeed arriving here after upgrading to version 6.

Comment: I was getting really annoyed that my tests suddenly stopped working.  I did a composer update and it updated my PHPunit to 6.1.  Thank You.

Comment: Here is an update link as linked file is gone in phpunit repository: (check [changelog](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/blob/9d0c024d2099531442d862b66b0ad7cf35ed8e78/ChangeLog-6.0.md))

Answer (score 53):

For **higher version** of phpunit such as **6.4**
You must use the namespace **PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase**

use **TestCase** instead **PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase**

```
// use the following namespace
use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;

// extend using TestCase instead PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
class SampleTest extends TestCase {

}
```

Comment: Excellent this worked for me as I was following an old tutorial

Comment: you just copied shadi's answer

Comment: @Adam who is shadi?

Comment: I don't know such a thing. I got same error then I explore answer by cracking the package

Answer (score 16):

I was running PHPUnit tests on PHP5, and then, I needed to support PHP7 as well. This is what I did:

In composer.json:

```
"phpunit/phpunit": "~4.8|~5.7"
```

In my PHPUnit bootstrap file (in my case, `/tests/bootstrap.php`):

```
// PHPUnit 6 introduced a breaking change that
// removed PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase as a base class,
// and replaced it with \PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase
if (!class_exists('\PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase') && class_exists('\PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase'))
    class_alias('\PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase', '\PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase');
```

In other words, this will work for tests written originally for PHPUnit 4 or 5, but then needed to work on PHPUnit 6 as well.

Comment: this solution important if you want to not touch Civi\Test code but need compatible with latest namespace based php unit test

Answer (score 13):

You may get this error because you namespaced the file.  If so you will need to specify that PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase is in the global namespace by preceding it with a backslash:

```
namespace AcmeInc\MyApplication\Tests
class StackTest extends \PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase {}
```

I submitted [a crude PR](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit-documentation/pull/245) to start conversation for correcting [the documentation](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/writing-tests-for-phpunit.html).

Comment: Yes, if you did this: `class YourNiceTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase` just add the \ in front of the extended class, like in `class YourNiceTest extends \PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase` - This worked for me, using `Symfony 2.8` and including the `phpunit` in the composer file downloaded as a local dependency with `"phpunit/phpunit": "^4.8"`

Answer (score 6):

You can simply install PHPUnit to run commands (https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/#php-archive-phar):

```
wget https://phar.phpunit.de/phpunit.phar
chmod +x phpunit.phar
mv phpunit.phar /usr/local/bin/phpunit
```

**Run single test**

And then run PHPunit test:

```
phpunit test.php
```

Content of test file is following:

```
<?php

class StackTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    protected function setUp()
    {
    }

    public function testSave()
    {

    }
}
```

**Run test suite**

Configuration of test suite: demosuite.xml. `demo` is directory containing all tests. Test files must be named as `*_test.php` (`suffix`).

```
<testsuites>
    <testsuite name="DemoTestSuite">
        <directory suffix="test.php">demo</directory>
    </testsuite>
</testsuites>
```

Test suite runs with following commands:

```
phpunit -c demosuite.xml --testsuite DemoTestSuite
```

Comment: This no longer works because latests PHPUnit no longer supports old class names such as `PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase`. You really have to use `... extends PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase`

Comment: Just saying that I had to first `mv phpunit /usr/local/bin/phpunit` and then `sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/phpunit`. Setting file as executable before moving it never worked on Vagrant Ubuntu. No idea why... But in case someone is struggling with this, I hope this will help.

Answer (score 4):

**Assumption:**

> *Phpunit (3.7)* is available in the console environment.

**Action:**

Enter the following command in the console:

```
SHELL> phpunit "{{PATH TO THE FILE}}"
```

**Comments:**

You do not need to include anything in the new versions of PHPUnit unless you do not want to run in the console. For example, running tests in the browser.

Answer (score 1):

I use ZF2 and work for me when replaced 'PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase' to '\PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase'

Answer (score 1):

I got it working with

```
include("vendor/autoload.php");
```

at the top of my test function.

Answer (score 0):

If you have Centos or other Linux distribution you have to install phpunit package, I did that with yum install phpunit and it worked. Maybe you can have to add a repository, but I think it has to work smooth with the default ones (I have CentOS 7)

Answer (score 0):

It may well be that you're running WordPress core tests, and have recently upgraded your PhpUnit to version 6. If that's the case, then the recent change to namespacing in PhpUnit will have broken your code.

Fortunately, there's a patch to the core tests at https://core.trac.wordpress.org/changeset/40547 which will work around the problem. It also includes changes to travis.yml, which you may not have in your setup; if that's the case then you'll need to edit the .diff file to ignore the Travis patch.

1. Download the "Unified Diff" patch from the bottom of  https://core.trac.wordpress.org/changeset/40547
2. Edit the patch file to remove the Travis part of the patch if you don't need that. Delete from the top of the file to just above this line:

   ```
   Index: /branches/4.7/tests/phpunit/includes/bootstrap.php
   ```
3. Save the diff in the directory above your /includes/ directory - in my case this was the Wordpress directory itself
4. Use the Unix patch tool to patch the files. You'll also need to strip the first few slashes to move from an absolute to a relative directory structure. As you can see from point 3 above, there are five slashes before the include directory, which a -p5 flag will get rid of for you.

   ```
   $ cd [WORDPRESS DIRECTORY]
   $ patch -p5 < changeset_40547.diff
   ```

After I did this my tests ran correctly again.

Answer (score 0):

**NOTICE:** Command `php bin/console generate:doctrine:crud` also create `TestController` in `src/Tests` so it can throw error when you tried to start server if you don't have `UnitTests`. Remove the file fix it!

Answer (score 0):

For me, it was because I ran

```
$ phpunit .
```

instead of

```
$ phpunit
```

when I already had a configured `phpunit.xml` file in the working directory.

Answer (score 0):

I am using php 5.6 on window 10 with zend 1.12 version for me adding

> require_once 'PHPUnit/Autoload.php';

before

> abstract class Zend_Test_PHPUnit_ControllerTestCase extends
>   PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase

worked. We need to add this above statement in ControllerTestCase.php file

Answer (score 0):

**PHPUnit With Composer Autoloader**

I am using composer and found myself battling through this issue. Neither the old style (`PHPUnit_Framekwork_TestCase`) or the new style (`\PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase`) worked for me. After reading through all the answers here and elsewhere, I found it to be quite trivial.

**NOTE:** PHP namespaces are case insensitive, however composer is *case-sensitive*...

```
// WRONG
class TestChild extends \PhpUnit\Framework\TestCase {

// RIGHT
class TestChild extends \PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase {
```

In the above example, note the change from `\PhpUnit\...` to `\PHPUnit\...`.
This makes all the difference with the composer autoloader.