# Class 'PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase' not found in Symfony2 project

Tags: php, symfony, phpunit

I'm developing a project in symfony2 and I'm new with unit testing.

I have installed PHPUnit 3.6.10 via PEAR and it works from the terminal when I digit the phpunit command.

I wrote my first test class following the SensioLab suggestions (http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/testing.html) but when I use the command

```
php -c app src/My/CalendarBundle/Tests/Calendar/CalendarTest.php
```

I got

```
Fatal error: Class 'PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase' not found in /Library/WebServer/Documents/calendar/src/My/CalendarBundle/Tests/Calendar/CalendarTest.php on line 7
```

Here you are my test class:

```
<?php
namespace My\CalendarBundle\Tests\Calendar;

use My\CalendarBundle\Calendar\Calendar;

class CalendarTest extends \PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    public function testGetNextMonth()
    {
        $calendar = new Calendar('09', '2012', null);        
        $result = $calendar->getNextMonth();

        $this->assertEquals(10, $result);
    }
}
```

I read this discussion [Why, Fatal error: Class 'PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase' not found in ...?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6065730/why-fatal-error-class-phpunit-framework-testcase-not-found-in) but the symfony documentation doesn't say to include PHPUnit...

What I'm doing wrong? 
Thank you

Comment: Try `phpunit -c app/ path/to/test.php`

Comment: You need to install phpunit. And use "phpunit ..." instead of "php ..." when you run tests as @Squazic said

Comment: Thank you both... It works! Why the php -c command doesn't work correctly?

Comment: Those flags are for phpunit, a testing program built for PHP using PHP

Answer (score 11):

I just had a similar issue (with DoctrineFixturesBundle), and solved it by **adding PHPUnit to Symfony** (as opposed to installing PHPUnit via PEAR).

What worked for me was:

1) add `"phpunit/phpunit": "4.0.*"` to the `require` section of `composer.json`:

```
{
    "require": {
        ...
        "phpunit/phpunit": "4.0.*"
    }
}
```

2) running from the commandline:

```
php composer.phar update phpunit/phpunit
```

Comment: Chances are you don't need phpunit in your production environment. That said I would add it to **require-dev** not **require**.

Comment: Or you can install it from command line: composer require --dev phpunit/phpunit (--dev parameter for placing the dependency to the require-dev section of composer.json )

Answer (score 0):

In case someone runs into a similar issue.

1- Install **PHPUnit** following [this procedure](http://symfony.com/doc/master/contributing/code/tests.html):

```
$ pear config-set auto_discover 1
$ pear install pear.phpunit.de/PHPUnit
```

2- Run your tests as described [here](http://symfony.com/doc/master/book/testing.html):

```
$ phpunit -c app/ src/My/CalendarBundle/Tests/Calendar/CalendarTest.php
```

The `-c app/` option will be looking for a configuration file in the `app/` directory. This configuration file is `app/phpunit.xml.dist`.