# PHPUnit is not reading configuration file?

Tags: php, phpunit, composer-php

I want to install PHPUnit with composer and followed this tutorial: https://jtreminio.com/2013/03/unit-testing-tutorial-introduction-to-phpunit/

I added

```
{
    "require-dev": {
        "phpunit/phpunit": "3.7.14"
    },
    "autoload": {
        psr-0": {
           "phpUnitTutorial": ""
        }
 }
}
```

to the file `composer.json`. Entering `./vendor/bin/phpunit` shows me that phpunit is installed.

This is my folder structure:

```
composer.json
composer.phar
phpUnitTutorial/
vendor/
```

I created a `phpunit.xml` file inside the `phpUnitTutorial` folder with the content

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<phpunit colors="true">
    <testsuites>
        <testsuite name="Application Test Suite">
            <directory>./phpUnitTutorial/Test/</directory>
        </testsuite>
    </testsuites>
</phpunit>
```

Further I created an file at `phpUnitTutorial/Test/StupidTest.php` with the content

```
<?php

namespace phpUnitTutorial\Test;

class StupidTest extends \PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    public function testTrueIsTrue(){
      $foo = ture;
      $this->assertTrue($foo);
    }
}
```

In the tutorial it is advised to do the following:

> From project root, run PHPUnit: $ vendor/bin/phpunit

with the following screenshot:

[image]

If I execute `$ vendor/bin/phpunit` inside the `phpUnitTutorial` folder then I receive the error

> bash: vendor/bin/phpunit: No such file or directory

which makes sense to me because the folder `vendor` is on the same level as the folder `phpUnitTutorial`. If I execute `$ ../vendor/bin/phpunit` I get

[image]

It says no test executed and it doesn't confirm that my configuration file was read. Why is it not executing the test?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, the `phpunit.xml` file should be in the root folder `/bin/` then the command `$ vendor/bin/phpunit` will work and the tests will actually be executed.

Secondly you need to change in the file `StupidTest.php`

the line

```
class StupidTest extends \PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
```

to

```
class StupidTest extends \PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase
```

see https://stackoverflow.com/a/42561590/2311074