# How do I get PHPUnit to work in PhpStorm?

Tags: php, xampp, phpunit, phpstorm

I am currently getting this message when I attempt to run a test in PhpStorm:

> C:\xampp\php\php.exe C:\xampp\htdocs\phpunit-test\tests\EmailTest.php
>
> PHP Fatal error:  Class 'PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase' not found in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\phpunit-test\tests\EmailTest.php on line 10
>
> Fatal error: Class 'PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase' not found in 
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\phpunit-test\tests\EmailTest.php on line 10
>
> Process finished with exit code 255

I am currently working with the following:

- XAMPP for Windows 5.6.24
- PhpStorm 2017.2.1
- PHPUnit-5.7.21.phar

The file and test I am running are exactly what is found on the PHPUnit website

I haven't made any special or particular changes to PhpStorm, so I do not understand what may be causing the default PHPUnit test to fail. Maybe I am missing something:

[image: My code]
(you can ignore the phpunit-6.3.0.phar file as it is in no way being used -- I was just trying to see if it made a difference or not what version of PHPUnit I was using)

EDIT: 8/23/2017

So I tried @Florian suggestion, and created a phpunit.xml AND a phpunit.xml.dist file, using the code found on [phpunit's website for version 5.7] and I now get this error:

[xml or xmldist fail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WzDxm.jpg)

I do not understand why, when I either use the phpunit.xml or phpunit.xml.dist file, I get these errors. Am I getting closer to resolving this or is there something else?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why, Fatal error: Class 'PHPUnit\_Framework\_TestCase' not found in ...?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6065730/why-fatal-error-class-phpunit-framework-testcase-not-found-in)

Comment: Read this as well https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/testing-with-phpunit.html

Comment: https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Testing+PHP+Applications

Answer (score 2):

You must set either the "Default configuration file" or the "Default bootstrap file" with a path to the config file.

The "Default configuration file" should be set to a `phpunit.xml.dist` file, more information about the file can be found under the section [Organizing Tests](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/organizing-tests.html#organizing-tests.xml-configuration)

or the other option is to give an `autoload.php` file to set some configurations. In the [PHPunit Getting started guide](https://phpunit.de/getting-started.html) it is listed in the `Test Execution`.

More information about [Autoloading](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php) from php.net

Comment: Hi Florian, I tried your solution but I ran into another issue. Please see the edit to my original post for the result.

Comment: Hi Alex, please make sure you have all tags inside the file. The error says that you're missing the closing phpunit tag