# PHP fatal error with phpunit on Symfony 3.3.8

Tags: php, symfony, phpunit

I've have this error on executing tests

> PHP Fatal error:  Class 'PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase' not found in
>   /vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Test/KernelTestCase.php
>   on line 24

I can solve with this change

```
use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;
...
abstract class KernelTestCase extends TestCase
```

by

```
abstract class KernelTestCase extends \PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
```

Is a bug or I'm miss some configuration on the version 3.3.8 of Symfony?

Thanks

P.S. differrent of [Why, Fatal error: Class 'PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase' not found in ...?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6065730/why-fatal-error-class-phpunit-framework-testcase-not-found-in)
the error is not Fatal error: Class 'PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase' not found in ...

Comment: You're probably missing the PHPUnit dependency in your vendor folder. Check your composer.json file if it's there. If it's in a `require-dev` list, install it using `composer update --dev`

Comment: How are you running the tests from the Symfony root folder? What is the `exact` command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've can fix the issue.
With PHPUnit 5.4.6 the tests works fine, but with PHPUnit 5.1.3 not.

The solutions are

```
update phpci
```

or

Add `/usr/share/php/PHPUnit/ForwardCompatibility/TestCase.php` to the  "problematic" server

```
<?php
/*
 * This file is part of PHPUnit.
 *
 * (c) Sebastian Bergmann <sebastian@phpunit.de>
 *
 * For the full copyright and license information, please view the     LICENSE
 * file that was distributed with this source code.
 */

namespace PHPUnit\Framework;

use PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase;

class TestCase extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
}
```

And add this class to /usr/share/php/PHPUnit/Autoload.php

```
    ...
$classes = array(
    'phpunit\\framework\\testcase' => '/ForwardCompatibility/TestCase.php',
...
```

Thanks.

Comment: You should accept your answer to make the question solved.