# PHPUnit Plugin in Netbeans 8.2 gives Fatal error: Class 'PHPUnit_Framework_TestSuite' not found when trying to run a test case

Tags: php, netbeans-8, netbeans-plugins, phpunit

When I try to run PHPUnit in Netbeans I face this error:

```
Fatal error: Class 'PHPUnit_Framework_TestSuite' not found in C:\Users\julian\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\8.2\phpunit\NetBeansSuite.php on line 63
Done.
```

This happens both in Netbeans and CLI.

---

I started debugging this problem by navigating to this directory:  `C:\Users\julian\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\8.2\phpunit\`.

That directory contained one file: `NetBeansSuite.php`. I opened it to look for clues, and saw this line:

```
class NetBeansSuite extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestSuite {
```

What I didn't see is any concrete `PHPUnit_Framework_TestSuite` class.

What's next is that the `NetBeansSuite.php` file doesn't have any `include` or `require` language constructs that may include the `PHPUnit_Framework_TestSuite` class.

So, in order to fix the fatal error problem I should include the `PHPUnit_Framework_TestSuite` in `NetbeansSuite.php`.

This is a problem because I'm not the author of `NetbeansSuite.php`.
On top of that the author of `NetbeansSuite.php` wrote this in the comment section:

```
 <b>WARNING: User changes to this file should be avoided.</b>
```

---

I read further in the comments:

```
 * Copyright 2010 Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.
```

I guess the `NetbeansSuite.php` file is outdated.

---

Searching on the net brought me to this stackoverflow question:

[Why, Fatal error: Class 'PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase' not found in ...?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6065730/why-fatal-error-class-phpunit-framework-testcase-not-found-in)

They claim that using a namespaced version of PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase should fix the problem. So I did what they wrote.

I stubbornly changed `NetBeansSuite.php`. 
Old code:

```
class NetBeansSuite extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestSuite {
```

New code:

```
require_once 'PHPUnit/Autoload.php';

use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;

class NetBeansSuite extends TestCase {
```

I tried to run the test case again, and this was the unfortunately result:

```
Fatal error: Declaration of CalculatorTest::setUp() must be compatible with PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase::setUp(): void in C:\wamp64\www\test\CalculatorTest.php on line 97
```

In other words, it gave me a new problem.

My system:

```
Windows 10
WAMP
php 7.2.14
PHPUnit 8.0.6
Netbeans version 8.2 (Netbeans PHPUnit plugin installed through Tools > Plugins. Version: 0.26.2)
```

---

My question is: does anybody know how the NetBeansSuite.php file should be like with the system described above?

---

The setUp method in my test case:

```
protected function setUp()
{
    $this->object = new Calculator;
}
```

---

Update: The Skeleton Generator project is abandoned. 
See link: https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit-skeleton-generator
So in order to fix the `Declaration of CalculatorTest::setUp() must be compatible with PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase::setUp()` error the corresponding return type declaration should be used in the test case.

```
// I added : void
protected function setUp(): void
{
    $this->object = new Calculator;
}

// : void needs to be added in the tearDown method as well
protected function tearDown(): void
```

Unfortunately, this gave me new problems:

```
Warning: require_once(PHPUnit/Autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\wamp64\www\test\CalculatorTest.php on line 4

Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'PHPUnit/Autoload.php' (include_path='.;C:\php\pear') in C:\wamp64\www\test\CalculatorTest.php on line 4
```

I solved this by manually installing PEAR and creating a new "PHPUnit" directory in `C:\php\PEAR`. Then I created a new `Autoload.php` file. I filled the content of `Autoload.php` with a `PSR-4` example file found at: https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/.

This solved the Autoload problem, but I faced a new problem during the execution of a test case.

```
C:\wamp64\www\test>phpunit CalculatorTest.php
PHPUnit 8.0.6 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.



Time: 170 ms, Memory: 10.00 MB

No tests executed!
```

It shows `No tests executed!` but I have 5 tests. 
I'll make a new question for this. 
Here it is: [PHPUnit 8 installed on Windows through PHAR shows No tests are executed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55401857/phpunit-8-installed-on-windows-through-phar-shows-no-tests-are-executed/55402107#55402107)

Comment: Could you add your setUp method of your test? Since it is not compatible it seems

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initially indeed you should update your namespaces since it has been changed in more recent versions of PHPUnit.

The error however indicates that your `CalculatorTest::setUp()` method is not compatible with the PHPUnit version. Could you maybe post that method here?

Comment: The setUp method looks like this: `protected function setUp() { $this->object = new Calculator; }`. No real rocket science. Skeleton generator wrote it actually. Maybe it has something to do with static / non static ??

Comment: @Julian actually that looks ok with later versions of PHPUnit. However how does the method look like at `PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase::setUp` ? Also how did you install PHPUnit? Since as far as i can see it is with a netbeans plugin? If yes which version would it be

Comment: I just installed it as a PHAR, used this link: https://phpunit.de/getting-started/phpunit-8.html and this: https://phpunit.de/manual/6.5/en/installation.html#installation.phar.windows

Comment: the PHPUnit plugin in Netbeans is Version: 0.26.2.

Comment: I solved the problem. PHPUnit Plugin Version 0.26.2 seems to be outdated. Therefore Skeleton Generator gives an out-dated test case too. So, I just used the example at the getting-started page and it worked. Link to getting-started page: https://phpunit.de/getting-started/phpunit-8.html

Comment: @julian, i suggest to install your dependencies with composer since they are always project specific and not locked to your IDE

Answer (score 0):

For the same issue, I directly changed the file "NetBeansSuite.php" (C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\8.2\phpunit) as following :

```php
class NetBeansSuite extends \PHPUnit\Framework\TestSuite {
```

After that, CLI and Netbeans was working.