# PHPUnit 8 installed on Windows through PHAR shows No tests are executed

Tags: php, netbeans-8, netbeans-plugins, phpunit

I installed PHPUnit through PHAR ( https://phpunit.de/getting-started/phpunit-8.html ) and added phpunit to my system variables in Windows 10.

Now I'm trying to run a test case with phpunit on the CLI, but PHPUnit shows `No tests executed!`. The point is that I have 5 test methods.

The class I'm trying to test is this:

```
class Calculator
{
    /**
     * @assert (0, 0) == 0
     * @assert (0, 1) == 1
     * @assert (1, 0) == 1
     * @assert (1, 1) == 2
     * @assert (1, 2) == 4
     */
    public function add($a, $b)
    {
        return $a + $b;
    }
}
```

Found at: https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/php/phpunit.html

And my test case is this:

```
require_once 'PHPUnit/Autoload.php';

use PHPUnit\Framework\TestSuite;

class CalculatorTest extends TestSuite {
//class CalculatorTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase {

    /**
     * @var Calculator
     */
    protected $object;

    /**
     * Sets up the fixture, for example, opens a network connection.
     * This method is called before a test is executed.
     */
    protected function setUp(): void {
        $this->object = new Calculator;
    }

    /**
     * Tears down the fixture, for example, closes a network connection.
     * This method is called after a test is executed.
     */
    protected function tearDown(): void {

    }

    /**
     * Generated from @assert (0, 0) == 0.
     *
     * @covers Calculator::add
     */
    public function testAdd(): void {
        $this->assertEquals(0, $this->object->add(0, 0));
    }

    /**
     * Generated from @assert (0, 1) == 1.
     *
     * @covers Calculator::add
     */
    public function testAdd2(): void {
        $this->assertEquals(1, $this->object->add(0, 1));
    }

    /**
     * Generated from @assert (1, 0) == 1.
     *
     * @covers Calculator::add
     */
    public function testAdd3(): void {
        $this->assertEquals(1, $this->object->add(1, 0));
    }

    /**
     * Generated from @assert (1, 1) == 2.
     *
     * @covers Calculator::add
     */
    public function testAdd4(): void {
        $this->assertEquals(2, $this->object->add(1, 1));
    }

    /**
     * Generated from @assert (1, 2) == 4.
     *
     * @covers Calculator::add
     */
    public function testAdd5(): void {
        $this->assertEquals(4, $this->object->add(1, 2));
    }  
}
```

When I type `phpunit -v` in CLI then I see this:

```
C:\wamp64\www\test>phpunit -v
PHPUnit 8.0.6 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

Usage:
  phpunit [options] UnitTest [UnitTest.php]
  phpunit [options] <directory>

Code Coverage Options:
  --coverage-clover <file>    Generate code coverage report in Clover XML format
  --coverage-crap4j <file>    Generate code coverage report in Crap4J XML format
  --coverage-html <dir>       Generate code coverage report in HTML format
  --coverage-php <file>       Export PHP_CodeCoverage object to file
  --coverage-text=<file>      Generate code coverage report in text format [default: standard output]
  --coverage-xml <dir>        Generate code coverage report in PHPUnit XML format
  --whitelist <dir>           Whitelist <dir> for code coverage analysis
  --disable-coverage-ignore   Disable annotations for ignoring code coverage
  --no-coverage               Ignore code coverage configuration
  --dump-xdebug-filter <file> Generate script to set Xdebug code coverage filter
```

My system:

```
Windows 10
WAMP
php 7.2.14
PHPUnit 8.0.6
Netbeans version 8.2 (Netbeans PHPUnit plugin installed through Tools > Plugins. Version: 0.26.2)

Installation method: PHP Archive (PHAR)
```

Can someone point me to the right thinking direction to solving this problem?

Why is PHPUnit telling me that No tests are executed?

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Support for the `@assert` annotation was removed a long time ago. And `PHPUnit/Autoload.php` was also removed years ago.

TL;DR You want to read the official [Getting Started](https://phpunit.de/getting-started/phpunit-8.html) guide (and not outdated information provided the vendor of an "IDE" that does not support up-to-date versions of PHPUnit anyway).

Comment: I didn't expect an answer from the original creator. It's an honor. Anyway, I fixed the problem by a couple of things. First, by modifying the test case (derived from getting-started Test Code) and choose another file to be tested (Email). The second, I used my own version of `src/autoload.php` (derived from prs4). The third, target files that are subjected to testing needed to move to `src`. The fourth, the test scripts should be called in CLI like this: `C:\wamp64\www>phpunit --bootstrap src/autoload.php tests`. Thanks for your help.